# How to get rid of the headsepline in all pages of a scrbook-based text?

Tags: scrlayer-scrpage

I am typing a document using scrbook class.

I have made some changes such as putting all page numbers in the top right and keeping the chapter titles on the same page that contains a section of the previous chapter.

Now I intend to get rid of the headsepline of all pages; I am also not using running titles.
I would like to keep only the page numbers in the top right of all pages.

Sorry for the apparent silly question but I have failed in finding this answer by myself on the web.

Thanks.

Comment: well without knowing how you managed to get the lines (they are not there by defaut) it is difficult to tell you how to get rid of them again. So show a small but complete example. Apart from this: don't search on the web, look in the documentation.

Comment: Thank you Ulrike.